# Android DB select max value in API 14+

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a SQLite database in my Android project and need to get the latest row in a table. I'm doing it this way:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(" + KEY_ROU_ID + ") FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE_ROU + ";", null, null);
```

However, this requires API level 16. Is there a way to do this that works with API level 14? E.g SQLiteDatabase.query()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main overload of [`SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html), which takes a string and an array of strings, exists as of API Level 1.

You are accidentally another overload, that only exists from API Level 16, and takes a cancellation token.

Just remove the last argument from your call.

Comment: Thanks. I did not see that version.

Comment: This also applies to  SQLiteDatabase.query, the overload with the cancellation token as the last parameter only applies to API Level 16 upwards. If you remove that parameter, it will call the overload for API Level 15 and below.

Answer (score -1):

Check the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) to make sure you're using it right. I tried using 2.2 and it worked fine for me.

Comment: It is not about the sql statements but about the methods in android. SQLitedatabase.rawQueery(...) is only possible to use from API level 16.

Comment: No its available from api level-1 db.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs);